# Python pass enum as the constructor parameter

Tags: python, enums, constructor

Does someone know, how can I use an Enum as class constructor parameter?
I have created such class:

```
class Coin(Cash, Enum):
    onePenny = 1
    twoPens = 2
    fivePens = 5

    ones = 0
    twos = 0
    fives = 0

    def __init__(self, val):
        if val == onePenny:
            Cash.value = onePenny.value
            Coin.ones += 1
        elif val == twoPens:
            Cash.value = twoPens.value
            Coin.twos += 1
        else:
            print('Not existing coin.')
```

When I'm trying to create an object, I get the NameError:

> NameError: name 'onePenny' is not defined

How to fix it?

Comment: Can you give us the broader context of what you're trying to do? It looks like you're on the wrong track.

Answer (score 0):

The `class` statement doesn't define a new scope, so you need to refer to it as you would outside the statement, as you did with `ones` and `twos`.

```
def __init__(self, val):
    if (val == Coin.onePenny):
        Cash.value = Coin.onePenny.value
        Coin.ones += 1
    elif (val == Coin.twoPens):
        Cash.value = Coin.twoPens.value
        Coin.twos += 1
    else:
        print('Not existing coin.')
```